# WPF border background bount to in application resource defined brush won't update when resource is updated

Tags: c#, wpf

**Hi,**

so this will be my **first** question as I did not find anything that could answer my problem.

---

**Initial Situation**

I defined a `SolidColorBrush` in my `<Window.Resources>`

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}"/> 
<Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">PeachPuff</Color>
```

Then I bound my `Border` to the `SolidColorBrush`

```
<Border Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=BackgroundBrush}" />
```

At application launch I read an xml file where the background color is saved.

```
// Some XML Loading stuff -> backgroundColor is a Color
this.Resources["BackgroundColor"] = backgroundColor;
```

This worked like a charme. I could change the Color in the xml file and the background of my border was whatever color I defined in the xml file.

---

**Actual Problem**

Now I moved the definition of the `SolidColorBrush` and the `Color` to my **App.xaml** file and changed the method to change the color to:

```
Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"] = backgroundColor;
```

But now the background of the border does not change anymore. It's just the default color of the border. No matter what I write in my xml file.

When I debug what's in

`Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"]`

the color that was assigned by

`Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"] = backgroundColor;`

is actually in

`Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"]`

but the background **is not changed**...

---

**Background**

I have two windows. An main window and a preference window. In the preference window I want to be able to change the FontFamily/Type/Weight/Color etc. of the main window.

My first approach was to define all styles in the main window resources and pass the values I want to change to the preference window and read out the changes and then update the resources in the main window resources.

As this worked very well I now wanted to move the styles to the app.xaml and read and update them there so I don't have to pass them to the preference window and read them from there again.

Comment: Are you still binding to the color with `DynamicResource`, or did you switch to a `StaticResource`?

Comment: Yes still binding to `DynamicResource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution.

I put the styles into a `ResourceDictionary` which actually didn't help anything.

**BUT:**

When I reload the resource dictionary after modifying it the styles get applied.

Actually I thought it would load the dictionary without the changes applied **before** clearing the merged dictionaries?

```
Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"] = this.SelectedBackgroundColor;

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
dictionary.Source = new Uri("ControlStyles.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

Comment: I'm almost positive you have some sort of hiding going on (see my answer). That's what it sounds like. It should work as described without that hack. Glad you found a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Can not reproduce. The following code works for me (border shows up as azure):

My one suggestion would be to make sure you removed the resource from the window. The XAML binding would bind to the closest resource which would be the window resource (not the app resource), so you would be binding to the resource you're not changing.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="Window">
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
            <Button Margin="10">Test</Button>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication3.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}"/>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">PeachPuff</Color>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.Resources["BackgroundColor"] = Colors.Azure;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the code to load the xml and set the Resources is in the Loaded event of the window. When I move it to the constructor the resources are correctly loaded. But I still cannot change them in any other method in my application. I need to be able to change them in my properties window also.